# Fragment Management with Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using the built in Navigation Drawer activity which, when opened navigates me to FagmentHome. Lets say I opened FragmentA and from FragmentA I navigate to FragmentB and after that when I press back button it brings me back to FragmentHome rather that navigating me to FragmentA. I'm using Backstack to while going from FragmentA to FragmentB but as I am using built in navigation activity so I have no idea if there is any usage of backstack from FragmentHome to FragmentA. 
Current Output: FragmentHome--> FragmentA-->FragmentB, When back pressed FragmentB-->FragmentHome
Expected Output:FragmentHome--> FragmentA-->FragmentB, When back pressed FragmentB-->FragmentA-->FragmentHome

Comment: Please consider removing the duplicate question as to the answer!

Comment: Add aswell your navgraph xml file and code snippets on how you are navigating to easier help you!